# Is it the ByteBuf always backed by a DirectByteBuffer in the First channelRead()?

Tags: netty

In the `ChannelInboundHandler.channelRead()` method, I want to call the `ByteBuf.nioBuffer()` method to get a ByteBuffer, for some logic use a library which is operated on NIO `ByteBuffer`(and other logic is operated on Netty's `ByteBuf`). But if every `ByteBuf.nioBuffer()` call cause a memory copy operation, it will be costly, and I may want to look for other resolution. So I wrote the following simple test as the tentative investigation:

```scala
object InboundReadBufferUnderlying {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap()
    val bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup()
    val workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup()
    bootstrap.channel(classOf[NioServerSocketChannel])
      .group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
      .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer[SocketChannel] {
        override def initChannel(ch: SocketChannel): Unit = {
          ch.pipeline().addLast(new InboundReadBufferUnderlyingHandler)
        }
      })
      .bind(60000)
  }

}

class InboundReadBufferUnderlyingHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

  override def channelRead(ctx: ChannelHandlerContext, msg: Any): Unit = {
    msg match {
      case m: ByteBuf =>
        // OUTPUT:
        //    nioBufferCount=1
        //    nioBufferClass=DirectByteBuffer
        // Is it means the ByteBuf is backed by a ByteBuffer(DirectByteBuffer) ?
        println("nioBufferCount=" + m.nioBufferCount())
        val nioBuffer = m.nioBuffer()
        println("nioBufferClass=" + nioBuffer.getClass.getSimpleName)
        ctx.writeAndFlush(m)

      case _ =>
        super.channelRead(ctx, msg)
    }
  }

}
```

The output of the above program:

```
nioBufferCount=1
nioBufferClass=DirectByteBuffer
```

According to Netty document, nioBufferCount() returns non `-1` value indicates it has at least one underlying `ByteBuffer`. My question is:

- In the first ChannelInboundHandler, whether the byteBuf received in channelRead() is always backed by the NIO `ByteBuffer`? and the `ByteBuffer` always is a `DirectByteBuffer`?

Answer (score 0):

This is an implementation detail ins depends on the transport itself. You should never assume it.

Comment: But if I just concern about the NioServerSocketChannel implementation, is that true? I am not quite understand the Netty source code, but I really want to do some optimzation for may application, even though write code based on implementation detail is not so well.

Comment: yes its true... at least for now